# From where does IP geographical location data come?

Tags: internet, ip, ipv4, geolocation

I don't understand how some sites (e.g. https://www.ultratools.com/tools/geoIpResult)
show country and town for an IP address. For example `193.45.10.135`:

```
Continent:  Europe
Country:  Germany
Country Code:  DE
Country CF:  99
Region: 
State:  Hamburg
State Code: 
State CF:  82
DMA: 
MSA: 
City:  Hamburg
Postal Code:  20001
Timezone:  Greenwich Mean Time
Area Code: 
City CF:  66
Latitude:  53.56111172
Longitude:  10.01805607
```

This is Akamai's IP address, so it's unlikely that someone using internet through a hotspot located in a datacenter via a tablet with GPS. And there are no LOC DNS records on this IP.

Whois records only show the country:

```
inetnum:        193.45.10.128 - 193.45.10.255
netname:        SE-AKAMAI
descr:          Akamai International BV
org:            ORG-AIB6-RIPE
country:        DE
admin-c:        NARA1-RIPE
tech-c:         NARA1-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         TELIANET-LIR
source:         RIPE # Filtered
```

So, is there some database where this data is located (maybe RIPE)?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this excellent Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software

> **The primary source** for IP address data is the regional Internet registries which allocate and distribute IP addresses amongst
>   organizations located in their respective service regions:
>
> - African Network Information Centre (AfriNIC)
> - American Registry for Internet Numbers (ARIN)
> - Asia-Pacific Network Information Centre (APNIC)
> - Latin American and Caribbean Internet Address Registry (LACNIC)
> - RIPE Network Coordination Centre (RIPE NCC)
>
> **Secondary sources include:**
>
> - Data mining or user-submitted geographic location data. For example, a weather web site might ask visitors for a city name to find
>     their local forecast. Another example would be to pair a user's IP
>     address with the address information in his/her account profile.
> - Data contributed by internet service providers.
> - Merging databases from different suppliers.
> - Guesstimates from adjacent Class C range[5] and/or gleaned from network hops.
>
> **Accuracy is improved by:**
>
> - Data scrubbing to filter out or identify anomalies.
> - Statistical analysis of user submitted data.
> - Utilizing third-party tests conducted by reputable organizations.

Comment: You should at least try and summarise or mention the main points here in your answer.

Comment: I already read this. The question is, HOW this databases are making (especially for datacenter ip range).

Comment: Well, that is usually the secret of creating GeoIP databases, so I doubt that you'll get the full details. But there are many ways, including looking at hops close to the intended destination, analysing latency and determining possible distances and locations.

Comment: Also, this article may be helpful (and no Karan, I will not summarize it as these are already short and to the point): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788408/how-do-you-make-a-geolocation-database

Comment: I tried traceroute for this ip, previous is located in Sweden.

Comment: Ok, if the primary is "The primary source for IP address data" in this case RIPE, where this information are located? (I can't find this on ripe website.)

Comment: What do you mean by "where this information are located"? Can you please clarify?

Comment: "What do you mean by "where this information are located"? Can you please clarify?" I mean how can I access to this database.

Comment: https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any information about Hamburg in query ip: 193.45.10.135

Comment: If you do a 193.45.10.135 -B query, you see that the IP is from Germany.  I'm not sure what else they do to narrow it down further.

Comment: whois is also show that, I've included this in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The primary sources of IP to Geolocation information are:

- WHOIS information
- RIRs (RIPE, APNIC, ARIN, LACNIC, AfriNIC, etc)
- ISPs (in the form of [geofeeds](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-google-self-published-geofeeds-02)).

This data is then further maintained by IP to Geolocation service providers in a systematic way in the form of Databases. All these services fetch their data from the above-mentioned primary sources. Along with the primary sources, they also get their data from user-reported information. The accuracy of such services differs depending upon the algorithm they are fetching the data and update cycle. Some famous IP to Geolocation service providers are:

- [ipgeolocation.io](https://ipgeolocation.io/)
- [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/)
- [db-ip.com](https://db-ip.com/)
- [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co/)
- [ip2location.com](https://www.ip2location.com/)

Comment: https://ipbase.com also offers a great API for IP geolocation lookups.